# Maximization with Expectation: How to Prove

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a set $N$ of i.i.d. non-negative random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n$. Then we weight them with positive constants $a_1X_1,\dots,a_2X_2$. Now we we want to select a subset $M$ with $m<n$ number of these weighted rvs such that the expected value of the ratio of the sum of the $m$ selected rvs to the sum of the rest of the random variables is the largest it can be. i.e. $$\mathrm{max}_{M\subset N}E\cfrac{\sum_{i\in M}a_iX_i}{\sum_{j\in N \setminus M} a_jX_j}.$$
The answer seems to be to sort the $a_i$s in descending order and take the first $m$ largest $a_i$s to the numerator and the rest to the denominator. But with the expectation I am not sure how to prove this.

Comment: $X_i$ are positive?

Comment: i was about to ask exactly ^^^^ what you said is false, if $X_n$ are all negative random variables, for example. if they are positive, it is easy. if it can be both, then life is harder... expectation might even necessarily be defined...

Comment: @leonbloy Yes they are non-negative. I will edit the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an interchanging argument. Suppose this is not the case, you have $a_k<a_l$ but $a_k$ is on the numerator and $a_l$ in the denominator. Since the numerator and the denominator are  independent, by exchanging $j$ and $i$, if $E(X_1)>0$, the expectation of the numerator is increased by this exchange. To see the denominator is also increased by the exchanged:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking on this line. But I have never come across a math proof like that. Will mathematicians approve such a proof?

Comment: @triomphe oh this is a well known result in optimisation theory. Since there are only finite many arrangement, the maximum must be attained. the thing i have written is a way of (strictly) improving your expectation. Only at a maximum, there is no possible improvement.